# Error when renaming columns with plyr in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, rename

I found similar error but it seems the problem is not the same.

```
for (i in colnames(t[,4:ncol(t)])) {
  for (j in poids_teff$station) {
    if (i == j) {
      t <- plyr::rename(t, c(i = poids_teff$nom_simplifie[poids_teff$station==j]))
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my error :
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: i
...
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: i

It seems the value passes as a string in the plyr when it should be a column name. I tried printing i and j to check and i had the right names.

I also tried dplyr but it says that the length does not match (but it does).

I checked the types and i and j are both characters. Printing i then poids_teff$nom_simplifie[poids_teff$station==j] gives this :

```
[1] "AGEN-LA GARENNE" 
[1] "AGEN" 
[1] "AUXERRE" 
[1] "AUXERRE" 
[1] "BALE-MULHOUSE" 
[1] "MULHOUSE"
```

Head of poids_teff gives this :

```
nom_simplifie   station    J Jmoins1 Jmoins2
AGEN       AGEN-LA GARENNE 0.64 0.24 0.12 
AUXERRE       AUXERRE      0.64 0.24 0.12 
MULHOUSE  BALE-MULHOUSE    0.64 0.24 0.12
```

Head of i gives this :

```
   year month day  AGEN-LA GARENNE    AUXERRE BALE-MULHOUSE 
1: 1949   1   1      6.9              NA       2.8 
2: 1949   1   2      5.9              NA       1.3 
3: 1949   1   3      2.9              NA       2.6
```

When i check typeof t and poids_teff they are bost lists.

Here is something that worked in python and that i'm trying to translate :

```
# for i in df_70.columns:
#   for j in poids_teff['nom_70 ans']:
#   if (i == j):
#   df_70 = df_70.rename(columns={i:poids_teff['nom_simplifie'][poids_teff.set_index('nom_70 ans').index.get_loc(j)]})
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your dataframe ?

Comment: Hello, 
I checked the types and i and j are both characters. Printing i then poids_teff$nom_simplifie[poids_teff$station==j] gives this :  [1]"AGEN-LA GARENNE"
[1] "AGEN"
[1] "AUXERRE"
[1] "AUXERRE"
[1] "BALE-MULHOUSE"
[1] "MULHOUSE"

Comment: Head of poids_teff gives this : 
 nom_simplifie              station    J Jmoins1 Jmoins2
1          AGEN      AGEN-LA GARENNE 0.64    0.24    0.12
2       AUXERRE              AUXERRE 0.64    0.24    0.12
3      MULHOUSE        BALE-MULHOUSE 0.64    0.24    0.12

Head of i gives this : 
 year month day AGEN-LA GARENNE AUXERRE BALE-MULHOUSE
1: 1949     1   1             6.9      NA           2.8
2: 1949     1   2             5.9      NA           1.3
3: 1949     1   3             2.9      NA           2.6 

When i check typeof t and poids_teff they are bost lists (dataframe)

Comment: Please put sample data in your question with nice formatting, not in comments with no formatting.

Comment: Hello I just changed that

Comment: up ? i don't find anything